# MonoTouch: UITabBarController throws 'loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set'

Tags: c#, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, monodevelop

I've been searching the web, but can't find a solution.

I create a new MonoTouch iPhone solution.

I create a new view called myTestView.

I add a `UITabBarController`.

I save and exit Interface Builder.

In `AppDelegate.cs` I have this code...

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    viewController = new myTestView ();
    window.RootViewController = viewController;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return true;
}
```

I run the app and get this error: **loaded the "myTestView" nib but the view outlet was not set**

Emmm I can't figure out what setting I miss. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

There is a default outlet for every XIB file called "view".

It must be hooked up to the root View you want in your ViewController, otherwise you get the message: "view outlet was not set".

So for example, let's say I want a new UITableViewController:

- File->New->File->iPhone View Controller
- Change my controller to inherit from UITableViewController in cs file
- Open the XIB file in XCode
- Delete the root UIView
- Add a UITableView to my file
- Right click on File's Owner and map the "view" outlet to the new UITableView with the stupid blue line thingy

This should resolve your error.

Comment: Hmmm - this changed my error to something new:  Name: UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Reason: A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UITableView: 0xd29c800; frame = (0 0; 748 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xca87570>; layer = <CALayer: 0xca81dd0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with <UITableViewController: 0xca88270>. Clear this association before associating this view with <RootViewController: 0x15c91480>.

Comment: Sounds like you have `view` hooked up twice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your new view as a View with Controller? This is the only view type that has worked for me.

You should also check a couple of additional things:

1) Ensure your constructor is present and correct in your main view file:

```
    //loads the myTestView.xib file and connects it to this object
    public myTestView () : base ("myTestView ", null)
    {
    }
```

2) Ensure the designer file was created correctly and has the correct information:

```
[Register ("myTestView")]
partial class myTestView
{
```